# How can I plot svm graph in R by using these data?

Tags: r

I used package `kernlab` and installed a function called `ksvm`. I built a ksvm model using data with 12x33 matrix. The first column of the matrix is the class (ie. 0 and 1). Other columns are numbers that used for classification.

How can I plot the graph of this svm model? I would like to plot a graph including support vectors and the margins.

Answer (score 0):

For package **kernlab**:

```
library("kernlab")
example(plot.ksvm)
```

For package **e1071**:

```
library("e1071")
example(plot.svm)
```